# Integration JIRA and Appspider

Tags: continuous-integration, jira-rest-api

Anyone have worked with integration between JIRA and Appspider using PowerShell? Any tips to share how to use both API?

It was given to me the task of integration JIRA to Appspider in order to every vulnerability found on Appspider is integrated to JIRA.

If someone has worked with it and could share any tip